# Vue2 Laravel5.3 How to send data from child to parent on event

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

What I am trying to achieve here is that when I click on the item in `Item-card-product-choices.vue` it will trigger `selectPC` with argument `productChoice.id` and this will also trigger parent to listen to this event and get the argument at the same time. I follow [the doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events) to do but parent does not seem to listen to `selectPC`. So please solve the following questions senpai:

1. what is wrong with my way for parent to listen to child's event?
2. when parent listens, how to get the argument the child use in the event too?
   Thanks.

Item-card-product-choices.vue

```
<template>
  <ul class="product-choices">
    <li 
    v-for="productChoice in productChoices"
    class="product-choice" 
    @click.prevent="selectPC(productChoice.id)"
    >
      <svg v-if="productChoice.color === 'red'" width="20" height="20">
        <rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:#FF3333"></rect>
      </svg>
      ......
      ......
      ......
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props:[
      'index',
      'product'
    ],
    data() {
      return {
        productChoices:{},
      }
    },
    methods:{
      selectPC(productChoice){
        var vm = this;
        vm.$emit('select',productChoice)
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
   ....
    <product-choices :product="product" @selectPC="getSelected(productChoice)"></product-choices>
   ....
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import productChoices from './Item-card-product-choices.vue';
  export default {
    components:{
      'product-choices':productChoices
    },
    data(){
      return{
        productChoiceSelected:{},
      }
    },
    methods:{
      getSelected(selected){
        var vm = this
          alert(1) // this is what I added to test if it listens 
        vm.$on('select',function(selected){
          vm.$http.get('/getProductChoice/'+vm.product.id+'/'+selected).then((response)=>{
            vm.productChoiceSelected = response.data
          });
        })
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you're emitting is named "select", not "selectPC" so you need to listen for that in `Parent.vue`

```
<product-choices :product="product" @select="getSelected"></product-choices>
```

Your `getSelected` method should not add an `$on` listener either...

```
getSelected(selected) {
  this.$http.get('/getProductChoice/' + this.product.id + '/' + selected).then(response => {
    this.productChoiceSelected = response.data
  })
}
```

Comment: So if I don't use `$emit`, according to the doc I shared, parent can actually listen to a method of child right? and isn't that what I was doing in my code there?

Comment: @warmjaijai the child component still needs to `$emit` the event. And as it says in the doc you shared... [*"You cannot use `$on` to listen to events emitted by children. You must use `v-on` directly in the template"*](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events). Note, `@select="..."` is the same as `v-on:select="..."`

Comment: Oh I saw the emit in the code now, in the doc the method increment and the emit increment confused me. Let me try your suggestion now thanks @Phil

Comment: But how do I get the data the child emits? will it just get it with @select=""?

Comment: @warmjaijai yes. The second argument passed to `$emit` will be passed to the function bound to the event, ie your `getSelected` method

Comment: this works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your suggestion